# high fidelity image size makes ms word file enormous

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, images

I am creating some MS Word files with instructions and there are pictures included. When I first printed the files or saved them as PDFs the picture quality was very poor, so I switched to high fidelity and not compressing the pictures. Now however I have extremely huge files - 1 file 1 page and 6 pics in total makes a file of 300 MB, which is insane. The original quality of a picture is no more than 3-4 MB so in total max. 20 MB for all pictures outside of the word file.
What can I do to preserve the quality of the pictures and to avoid that size of the files?

Comment: How are you inserting the images? Are you using the proper 'Insert image" tool or are you copy pasting from some image editor? https://superuser.com/a/457784/19943

Comment: hannu has it buried in their answer: try to actually calculate the pixel dimensions of the images when placed, then create a set of images that are sized correctly. If the document is 150ppi, and you place a 3 inch square image, it should be 450px x 450px. no larger

Comment: I am inserting them with "insert image".

Comment: What is the format of the images you insert? Try to play with it jpeg / png should work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> not compressing the picture

Do compress the images, but reduce the quality (compression harshness).

**Then also note:**
If you have a 46MP image (as from a Nikon 800 series DSLR) it will be 14 MB as saved in RAW format; the actual RAW data contains 4 channels of 14 bits actual data (stored in 16 bits?), so 46x2x4 bytes = 368MB data, plus the metadata (e.g. Exif).

Save it as a JPG and the stored data (when uncompressed) is still 46x3 MB of data, which likely is the same amount of RAM required to store the image while handling it in Word.

**Calculate:** 150 PPI(!) requirement for a "good" image resolution, to be printed (if NOT a PDF) 3 inches wide: 150x3 = 450 pixels minimum required; 2 inches high => 300 pixels required ==>> 450x300 pixels minimum [1].

To display it on a 1280x1024 resolution monitor (not full width) I'd chose to insert a 1024 pixel image, or step up to 2048 to allow to zoom in it.

In the same manner to "support" even higher resolution monitors; use the monitor's native resolution height as a 'default' value for the image width in pixels.

**Another approach:**
View the image on screen, any image viewer. Use e.g. <kbd>'Win'</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (Windows 10) to frame and grab the part of the image you need, and paste it in the document. This most often gives a slightly zoomable image in PDF:s. Assuming High quality setting in e.g Acrobat Pro.

[1] Note here that a PRINTER uses "DOTS" to create the print (hence DPI, not PPI), in actual print it might be a matrix of 6x6 dots for a single pixel in an image.

Comment: I must confess, that I got lost in your explanation, but the problem is on my end. I will try to explain the issue in more detail and will be very happy to get your support. 
So I have a bunch of almost 50 pictures taken be a phone, all of them with resolution 4624x2604 and they all need to be cropped and corrected bit. I need to spread them upon several MS Word files that later on I need to send as a PDF to a professional print service. Pictures size within the document must be 4,5 x 3 cm. What px size would you recommend to preselect to preserve  the quality and the images to remain sharp?

Comment: Also the default resolution in MS Word is 220 ppi, but it can be increased to 330ppi or high fidelity. What would be the best option in this case?

Comment: Well with nothing else changed, going "x" PPI to "x+n" PPI is likely to only cause your document display to grow(?); change size at least.

Comment: Hmm... thinkn I had that key combination wrong, not quite sure it is correct now either (doing without thinking, all the time)

Comment: I managed to solve it somehow. So I actually opened GIMP and scaled each picture down to 1200 px width. It reduced the pic size heavily, so keeping all other settings as is, I managed to create a file "only" 40 MB big. Still quite big, but compared to the  500 MB before is manageable to work with. Thanks for your input

Comment: That's nice! =)

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to implement, you can try to compress the picture while keeping the high fidelity, which may compress the image size. Or you don't have to choose high fidelity and choose 150ppi resolution.